# Extracting Ethnicity by Study Groups in r when columns are factors

Tags: r, factors, tapply

I have a csv file which contains cancer data for two study groups: A and A   Follow-up (eg, before and after treatment). The data are presented as follows:

```
ID           Ethnicity        Study Group    
45A          Caucasian        A  
45B          Caucasian        A - follow up  
68A          Asian            A    
68B          Asian            A - follow up
```

Both Ethnicity and Study Group are currently factors. I'd like to extract out the total by ethnicity by study group but struggling to find a way forward. Any help welcome.

Comment: And how is it a problem that they are factors?

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: @jeremycg - see below please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
pairedAB %>% group_by(Study.Group, Ethnicity) %>%
        summarise(number = n())
```

Comment: How do you know that this is the expected output?.

Comment: Be patient guys. It takes time to understand programming and ask the right questions. Thank you. I will give the above solution a go...

Comment: My data = pairedAB. Using the above and substituting dat for pairedAB returns this:   "Study.Group" "Ethnicity" number
1   Study.Group   Ethnicity     64. This isn't what I'm after. I need to split the groups into "A" and "A - follow-up" and then within each return the number of women who fall into each ethnic group. Under Ethnicity, these groups are "Black", "Asian" and "Caucasian". Cheers

Comment: Just to qualify: both columns are contained in df called "pairedAB"

Comment: Hi, I have 64 observations so doing that would return a long list that I don't think would be welcome. Ethnicity and Study Group are 2 columns from this data. The patients are listed by row with 64 observations in columns. What I'd like to achieve is pulling out Ethnicity by the 2 study groups to start with, then doing the same for observation of interest (eg, HPV infection - which dramatically changes pre-and post treatment), Does that help? In the original, I just simplified by taking the first 2 columns of interest. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: try now - the problem is you have referred to "Study Group" and Study.Group interchangably - we can;t tell which your data has unless you use a dput. See [the reproducible example faq](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: You just contributed to cancer research. Many thanks for your interest.

Comment: Full working code for clarity for anyone else:

dput(head(pairedAB)) 
pairedAB %>% group_by(Study.Group, Ethnicity) %>%
        summarise(number = n())

Answer (score 0):

Provided that the `dplyr` answer by @jeremycg produced the correct output (as the question doesn't have an expected output), here is the `data.table` alternative:

```
library(data.table)
pairedAB[,.(number=sum(length(ID))),by=c("Ethnicity","Study.Group")]
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll try both. Cheers.

Comment: You might want to tick the check mark below the voting of the answer you found more useful, that encourages people to answer your further questions ;)

Comment: Hi, unfortunately the above code didn't work for me. But I would be interested in any further tweaks. Thanks